# Sailboat found on an Indian reservation with a portal to different planets

Tags: story-identification

I thought it was "Distant Shores" but can't find it under that name.  People find a sailboat from the far past on an Indian reservation.  Upon further digging they find a portal to different planets.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! This is a good overview of the premise but can you remember anything else? Do they go through the portals? Any specific plot points? How old was this? Is it a book, TV show, film, cartoon, etc.? If you remember anything else or want to change what you have here please [edit] your post to do so!

Comment: @DR ROBERT E PETERSEN - If anyone correctly identifies the story you're looking for, please mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

Might this be *[Ancient Shores](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/535315.Ancient_Shores)* (1996) by Jack McDevitt, the first book in the *[Ancient Shores](https://www.goodreads.com/series/161579-ancient-shores)* duology...?

> It turned up in a North Dakota wheat field: a triangle, like a shark's fin, sticking up from the black loam. Tom Lasker did what any farmer would have done. He dug it up. And discovered a boat, made of a fiberglass-like material with an utterly impossible atomic number. What it was doing buried under a dozen feet of prairie soil two thousand miles from any ocean, no one knew. True, Tom Lasker's wheat field had once been on the shoreline of a great inland sea, but that was a long time ago -- ten thousand years ago.
>
> A return to science fiction on a grand scale, reminiscent of the best of Heinlein, Simak, and Clarke, Ancient Shores is the most ambitious and exciting SF triumph of the decade, a bold speculative adventure that does not shrink from the big questions -- and the big answers.

[This review](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/jack-mcdevitt/ancient-shores/) confirms that the story involves an interplanetary transportation device buried beneath a Sioux reservation:

> **Astonishingly, North Dakota farmer Tom Lasker unearths a perfectly preserved 42-foot sailboat from his wheatfield. More remarkable still, the boat is made of materials unknown to science- -and has probably lain buried for ten thousand years, since it last sailed the waters of an ancient glacial lake.** While tourists line up to goggle at the boat—its automatic lights still work—Tom's pilot friend Max Collingswood and scientist April Cannon wonder whether there's a boathouse, too. **Sure enough, a geophysics survey reveals a mysterious structure buried on the nearby Sioux reservation. Max and April negotiate permission to dig and soon uncover a glassy circular building that contains a transporter device connecting it to another planet hundreds of light-years away.** But, clearly, these advanced technologies threaten global economic stability, and the President comes under pressure to secure the building and destroy it (having, apparently, forgotten about the a sailboat, which Tom has already sold). The Sioux resist, however, and just as a dreadful slaughter seems unavoidable, Max ferries in a planeload of luminaries to broadcast the truth of the world. From familiar components, McDevitt (The Engines of God, 1994, etc.) has fashioned a solidly engrossing tale that, despite some plot wobbles, brims with low-key attractions.

Comment: @DR ROBERT E PETERSEN - If anyone correctly identifies the story you're looking for, please mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. Thanks.

Comment: This is what immediately came to my mind too. I didn't know it was a duology!

Comment: The reviews of the sequel are dismal enough that I passed on it.

Comment: I recommend you pass on the sequel.  'Dismal' does not begin to cover it.